# What is the most common practice in retrieving large amounts of data such as usernames, from firebase to parse to check for availability?

Tags: firebase

Currently I am pulling them all into an array to parse, but I do not feel that will be as advisable when the user count starts exceeding a certain threshold.

Comment: A few more links in addition to the ones from Jen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970681/enforcing-unique-usernames-with-firebase-simplelogin, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339092/a-way-to-enforce-a-unique-property-in-firebase, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than retrieving the data and downloading it to the client, I recommend using Cloud Functions for Firebase. That way, the data remains private and can be processed quickly. See an answer I gave to this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932638/proper-way-to-maintain-unique-usernames-and-extra-profile-data-in-firebase/44933300#44933300).

Also check out these resources to get started with Cloud Functions for Firebase:

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Usage Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/EvV9Vk9iOCQ)